# How to parse (via loop) through a string until the end of the string?

Tags: java, string, loops, java.util.scanner

> Given String "5 6 7 8 9 2 3 " how do you use a while loop or for loop to cycle through each number without repeating the string (as a while loop would)?

```
 String myString = "5 6 7 8 9 2 3";

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myString);
while(myScanner.hasNext())
{
//do something
}
```

> I can't get the loop the stop. It keeps repeating the same string pattern over and over and over.

Comment: Try looking at what methods scanners have, ie [`scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

Comment: If you don't consume any input from the scanner, then when the while loop asks the scanner if it has more input, the scanner will always say yes.  In other words, where it says `//do something`, you should do something.

Comment: Solved it. Just used a for loop alone. Thanks.

Comment: A while loop will work fine if you just use something like ``String s = myScanner.next();``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far your code asks whether the scanner has more items. But you never consume them. So inside your loop you need to call something like

```
String currentItem = myScanner.next();
```